# Using user input to get information from a class

Tags: python

```
class employees:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first=first
        self.last=last
        self.email=first + '.' +last+ '@abc.com'
        self.fullname=first+' '+last


em1=employees('Jon', 'Baker')
val=input()
print(val)
```

What im trying to do is type . in the input() in the terminal to get 'Jon'. But instead it just prints out 'em1.first' is there a way i can fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure this is worth doing as it isn't scaleable at all. Are you trying to solve a particular problem in the long-run with this kind of approach or is this purely learning?

Comment: User input cannot interact directly with variable names?

Comment: @Fanatique well it can, since the only thing needed to make this work is to commit a cardinal sin and use `val=eval(input())`. This is not a good approach at all; [eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: You ran into difference between python2 and three. In py2 would have been the behavior of `al=eval(input())` as hinted above (and yes, really, don't). In py3 it's what `raw_input()` used to be in 2. And for a good reason.